# Injecting logger, weld

Tags: web-services, ejb-3.0, cdi, jboss-weld

I am trying to replace standard logger initialization by some injection

1-st.

I was trying to use weld [weld logging](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/extensions.html)  in stateless bean/webservices

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class EchoSSL {

    @Inject
    private Logger log;


    public EchoSSL() {
    }

    public String echo(String msg) {
        log.debug("Log test");
        return "Echoing: " + msg;
    }
}
```

But it not working for me.. i get java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:326)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:102)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:110)
>   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:195)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.FilterChainImpl.invokeFilterChain(FilterChainImpl.java:139)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:376)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:329)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:297)
>   ... 24 more Caused by:
>   javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:189)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:130)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:140)
>   at $Proxy484.sayHello(Unknown Source)
>   ... 29 more Caused by:
>   javax.ejb.EJBException at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5070)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:4968)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4756)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:200)
>   at $Proxy464.sayHello(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.InvokerImpl.invoke(InvokerImpl.java:78)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.EjbInvokerImpl.invoke(EjbInvokerImpl.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:146)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:257)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:95)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:138)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.tx.service.TxServerPipe.process(TxServerPipe.java:306)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:112)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:195)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:127)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:295)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:519)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:288)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:143)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:116)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:87)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:196)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:127)
>   ... 22 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   ua.eset.inferno.heresy.ws.security.Hello.sayHello(Hello.java:33)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1056)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1128)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5243)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5215)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5203)
>   at
>   com.sun.ejb.containers.WebServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(WebServiceInvocationHandler.java:188)
>   ... 66 more

What is missed ?

2-nd

than I try this [tutorial](http://glauche.de/2009/08/) that is referenced to this - [Custom Injections](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections)

But it also dosen`t help.

maven dependencies -

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-logger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-CR2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Q1: What is the rule of weld Logger injection in ejb / web services ?**

**Q2: Could it be wsdl/EJB/WebService issue ?**

Comment: Give the whole exception (+stacktrace)!

Comment: added..
I just can`t inject it (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your bean is in a bean archive - i.e. that you have `META-INF/beans.xml`

Apart from the weld extension, which I can't help you with unless you give the whole exception, you can create a producer  that `@Produces` a `Logger`

Comment: I was using mvn dependency for

            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-logger</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-CR2</version>

            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Alpha1</version>

            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-CR2</version>

            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-CR2</version>

Something else?

Answer (score 2):

This is my approach:

Add the following dependencies to the pom.xml:

```
<!-- SL4J API -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <!-- SLF4J JDK14 Binding  -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <!-- Injectable Weld-Logger -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
 <artifactId>weld-logger</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-CR2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Inject the Logger and use it as usual:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class Example {
  @Inject
  private Logger logger;

  public void exampleFunc() {
    logger.info("Hello Logger!");
  }
}
```

If you wanna use Log4J instead of the SLF4J-JDK14-binding, i found [this page](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/schaefa/archive/2007/08/to_the_hell_wit_1.html). I tried it, but i couldn't get it to work so i still stick with my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

The default slf4j logger producer is defined in [Weld Extensions](http://relation.to/Bloggers/WeldExtensionsAlphaAvailable#H-InjectableLogger).  You can see how the producer is written [here](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/weld/extensions/trunk/src/main/java/org/jboss/weld/extensions/log/LoggerProducer.java) if you wanted to wire up your own without including all of Weld Extensions.

Comment: I took that class copy it into my classpath, but no result - same story, same exception ..
Look like I miss understand whole idea.. goo to read weld specification and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

in this case I haven`t placed bean.xml in META-INF.